# How to make QSortFilterProxyModel stop showing incomplete matches in search results?

Tags: c++, qt, qsortfilterproxymodel

I'm writing a database management application project for an animal shelter in which I use `QSortFilterProxyModel` to show search results. The problem is that the proxy model search shows even incomplete matches. For example if I have three animals with the ids 35, 388 and 3 and I search for an animal with id 3, it shows me all 3 of them because their ids all contain 3.

Here some of my code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
    ui->setupUi(this);

    proxyModel1 = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
    proxyModel1->setSourceModel(&model);
    ...
    connect(idEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString&)), this, SLOT(searchChanged()));
}

void MainWindow::searchChanged() {

    proxyModel1->setFilterRegExp(QRegExp(idEdit->text(), Qt::CaseInsensitive));
    proxyModel1->setFilterKeyColumn(0);
}
```

I need to stop that from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that serves to filter an exact string does not exist so it must be implemented override the [`filterAcceptsRow()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#filterAcceptsRow) method:

```cpp
class SortFilterProxyModel: public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
public:
    using QSortFilterProxyModel::QSortFilterProxyModel;
    QString fixedString() const{
        return m_fixedString;
    }

    void setFixedString(const QString &fixedString){
        if(m_fixedString == fixedString) return;
        m_fixedString = fixedString;
        invalidateFilter();
    }

protected:
    bool filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent) const override{
        if(m_fixedString.isEmpty())
            return true;
        QModelIndex ix = sourceModel()->index(source_row, filterKeyColumn(), source_parent);
        return ix.data().toString() == m_fixedString;
    }
private:
    QString m_fixedString;
};
```

```cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
    ui->setupUi(this);

    proxyModel1 = new SortFilterProxyModel(this);
    proxyModel1->setSourceModel(&model);
    connect(idEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, this, &MainWindow::searchChanged);    
}

void MainWindow::searchChanged() {
    proxyModel1->setFixedString(idEdit->text());
    proxyModel1->setFilterKeyColumn(0);
}
```

Comment: I can't understand why but actually doing this fix didn't change anything :(

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure I'm calling searchChanged... and with the new fix still nothing changes, could it be because the id attribute in my logical model is actually an integer?

Comment: @Diba You are correct, the documentation is confusing, setFilterFixedString filters the words that contain the text so you do not see any difference, in this case it is to implement a custom method, try my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can get what you want by making your text a regular expression for an exact match by starting with ^ and ending in $.

```
proxyModel1->setFilterRegExp(QRegExp('^' + idEdit->text() +'$', Qt::CaseInsensitive));
```